# allow firewall after first time disallow

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, uac

I'm using win10 with UAC enabled, typically this is my working laptop so cannot disable UAC.

When download a exe or jar, try to execute it, sometimes windows firewall will prompt whether allow or not allow it listen to traffic of specific port(I never read carefully but thought was saying something sililiar). But my company pc require special steps to run as admin(or in common cases we forget or mistype the strong password), the first time I acutally disabled the software.

Then I prepare UAC first and run the binary as admin, but always report error about port using disabled. I looked in the firewall settings-allow app or feature through... but cannot find the binary name. maybe it could be using some other name than the binary name.

So how to enable one app through firewall if first time you disabled it?

Answer (score 0):

If unsure of the binary name, try going to firewall settings > allow app, then remove all items which are *not* allowed through the firewall.

Windows should then re-ask what to do for these applications - and hopefully, this will be the case for the app you are interested in.

Comment: there are many not allowed. and some are not allowed with intent so cannot remove all. and remove all is a time consuming task.

Comment: Then if you have an idea of the path where your binary resides, you could search it in the registry under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules`. This is where the firewall rules are stored; binaries are listed here with their full path.

Comment: have checked but the it is a list of uuids and you cannot see the useful information unless you select and modify one item.

Comment: You can use regedit to search for a given string in the keys data.